# Property 'passwordRules' not found on object of type 'UIView<RCTBackedTextInputViewProtocol> *'

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

Getting these errors on initializing a new react native app:

1. Property 'passwordRules' not found on object of type 'UIView *'
2. Use of undeclared identifier 'UITextInputPasswordRules'

[image]

### Steps to reproduce:

```
> react-native init sampleapp
> cd sampleapp
> xed ./ios
> (Click Run button)
```

### Environment Details:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2
xcode: 9.4.1
macos: 10.13.4
node: 12.14.1
npm: 6.13.7
cocoapods: 1.9.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try updating Xcode to the latest. I was stuck in Mojave so couldn't update the Xcode. But after Catalina + latest Xcode. Build worked.

Xcode 9.x definitely not gonna work with react native 0.60.0+